# Web Development :: VSCode, Live Server Plugin, Firefox -- Browser Always Caching, Not Refreshing

Tags: visual-studio-code, caching

I'm using VSCode, Live Server plugin for HTML5 web development.  When i make a change to my web page then save Live Server should refresh what i see within Firefox.  It does refresh but it is always to the oldest cache of the web page when live server first started up.  I must always tap CTRL-F5 to force a web page refresh within firefox.  The moment i save again within VSCode, the browser display reverts right back to the oldest, first copy.

I've already tried enabling "Disable Cache" within the FF Dev Tools > Networking area.  Didnt help.  I've tried about.config | browser.cache.disk.enable set to false.  Didnt help.

Just wondering if this is normal behavior or if the Live Server plugin (Ritwick Dey) for VSCode is broken.

At the present time

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seemsthe problem was i was using a service worker (sw.js).  The browser saw the file, autoloaded it and apparently took full control over caching in the browser -- basically, no matter what i did caching and refreshing was meaningless.  I really need to understand this sw.js thing.